# Java8 IntStream with limit+parallel

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to pass the 1Z0-809 Oracle certification. I was just coding some Dump and I finally get here.

```
public final class ParallelStreams{
   private long d=0,add=0,after=0;
   public static void main(String[] args){
       final ParallelStreams clazz = new ParallelStreams();
       IntStream.iterate(1,p->p+1)
            .peek(a->clazz.add++)
            .limit(5)
            .peek(a->clazz.after++)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(i->++clazz.d);

    System.out.println("clazz = " + clazz.d+" "+clazz.add+" "+clazz.after);
    }    
}
```

I know this is not the best thing to do. But something really caught my attention. The output to this is something like

```
clazz = 5 15451 5
```

Says that the 1 peek method was called a amazed 15451 times even when the limit is just 5? How this should be grasp the peek in all the threads pass this piece of the code 15451 times to finally stops it when the stream had 5? Or so?

Comment: You are updating `long` values from different threads in a way that is not thread safe. Plenty of different outcomes are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I executed your program I got the output:

```
clazz = 5 20 5
```

Adding some print statements:

```
IntStream.iterate(1,p->p+1)
    .peek(a->{ System.out.println("add - " + a); clazz.add++; })
    .limit(5)
    .peek(a->{ System.out.println("after - " + a); clazz.after++; })
    .parallel()
    .forEach(i->{ System.out.println("d - " + i); ++clazz.d; });
```

The output is:

```
add - 1025
add - 3073
add - 1
add - 6145
add - 2
add - 3074
add - 1026
add - 3075
add - 3
add - 6146
add - 6147
add - 4
add - 3076
add - 1027
add - 3077
add - 5
add - 6148
add - 6149
add - 1028
add - 1029
after - 3
after - 2
after - 5
d - 2
d - 3
d - 5
after - 1
after - 4
d - 1
d - 4
clazz = 5 20 5
```

To understand this, here are some excerpts from the documentation.

[java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

[IntStream.peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#peek-java.util.function.IntConsumer-):

> For parallel stream pipelines, the action may be called at whatever time and in whatever thread the element is made available by the upstream operation.

[IntStream.limit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#limit-long-):

> While limit() is generally a cheap operation on sequential stream pipelines, it can be quite expensive on ordered parallel pipelines, especially for large values of maxSize, since limit(n) is constrained to return not just any n elements, but the first n elements in the encounter order.

`peek` doesn't know about `limit` operation, so it's randomly executed N number of times  before `limit` is executed. Notice that once the lines with `after -` and `d -` are printed, no line with `add -` is printed.

These `after -` and `d -` lines print from 1 to 5 but neither `peek` nor `forEach` guarantee the order of the stream when working with parallel streams.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `limit` on a parallel stream. `limit` depends on the encounter order and when executed in parallel it has to buffer all the previous items to determine whether to push a particular item to the next step or not. Hence it buffers more items before making that decision. Your approach is inherantly sequential and you are trying to execute it in parallel, which is very ineficient and won't give you any speedup. Oneway to get over this is to remove the `.parallel()` from your stream pipeline like so,

```
   IntStream.iterate(1,p->p+1)
        .peek(a->clazz.add++)
        .limit(5)
        .peek(a->clazz.after++)
        .forEach(i->++clazz.d);
```

Now you will get the correct result.

Comment: hi why is the diff between the encounter order of the IntStream.iterate vs Range? thanks pal